# How can I position a menu to the right in a menubar

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a top menu in a menu bar like so: Income Expenses Users. I tried to put Users on the far right of the menu bar without success I used border pane. Is there a way to put first two menus as float left and the third menu floated to the right ?

Income Expenses Users

```
public class Budget extends Application {

Stage window;
BorderPane layout;


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    window = primaryStage;
    window.setTitle("First stage");

    Menu income = new Menu("Income");
    Menu expense = new Menu("Expense");
    Menu users  = new Menu ("Users");


    MenuItem addIncome = new MenuItem("Add Income..");

    income.getItems().add(addIncome);
    income.getItems().add(new MenuItem("List All Incomes"));

    expense.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Add Expense..."));
    expense.getItems().add(new MenuItem("List All Expenses"));

    users.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Switch User"));
    users.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Log In"));
    users.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Log Off"));

    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(income, expense, users);


    layout = new BorderPane();
    layout.setTop(menuBar);
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 600, 400);

    //Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 600, 400);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();

}

 /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 different menubars, then put them into `HBox`. The left menubar will contain "Income" and "Expenses", while the right one will have "Users". Use HBox's alignment options.

Comment: Thank you Uluk Biy . It worked ; I had to set the dimensions of the menus afterward but I think It's not an important issue.